# How to add to junction table of many-to-many relationship in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am having trouble adding to and accessing the junction table in my MVC project. Currently, I have a class of ApplicationUsers which is stored in the AspNetUsers default table. Additionally, I have a class of Projects which is stored in a respective table. Users can have multiple projects, and projects can have multiple users. I can't access the junction table from my controller, nor can I do something like: `db.Projects.Users.add(...)` without getting an error message that DbSet does not contain a definition for Users.

Here is my ApplicationUser class:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Claims;
using IssueTracker.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace IssueTracker.Areas.Identity.Data
{
   public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
   {
       public ApplicationUser()
       {
           this.Projects = new HashSet<ProjectModel>();
       }

       public String? FirstName { get; set; }

       public String? LastName { get; set; }

       public String? Role { get; set; }

       public virtual ICollection<ProjectModel> Projects { get; set; }
   }
}
```

and here is my Projects class:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using IssueTracker.Areas.Identity.Data;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace IssueTracker.Models
{
    public class ProjectModel
    {
        public ProjectModel()
        {
            this.Users = new HashSet<ApplicationUser>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string? Name { get; set; }

        public string? Description { get; set; }

        public string? Status { get; set; }

        public string? ClientCompany { get; set; }

        public string? ProjectLeader { get; set; }

        public ICollection<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }

    }
}
```

This is my DbContext:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;
using IssueTracker.Models;

namespace IssueTracker.Areas.Identity.Data;

public class IssueTrackerIdentityDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<ProjectModel> Projects { get; set; }

    public IssueTrackerIdentityDbContext()
    {

    }

    public IssueTrackerIdentityDbContext(DbContextOptions<IssueTrackerIdentityDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new ApplicationUserEntityConfiguration());

        builder.Entity<ProjectModel>()
                .HasMany<ApplicationUser>(s => s.Users)
                .WithMany(c => c.Projects);
    }


}

public class ApplicationUserEntityConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicationUser>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ApplicationUser> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(u => u.FirstName).HasMaxLength(255);
        builder.Property(u => u.LastName).HasMaxLength(255);
    }
}
```

and lastly, here is my controller where I am getting the error message:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using IssueTracker.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using IssueTracker.Areas.Identity.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using System.Security.Claims;

namespace IssueTracker.Controllers;

[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private IssueTrackerIdentityDbContext db;
    private UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager;
    private RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager;

    public HomeController(IssueTrackerIdentityDbContext db, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
    {
        this.db = db;
        this.userManager = userManager;
        this.roleManager = roleManager;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult CreateProject()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult CreateProject(String Name, String Description, String Status,
        String ClientCompany, String ProjectLeader, List<string> Contributors)
    {
        var project = new ProjectModel
        {
            Name = Name,
            Description = Description,
            Status = Status,
            ClientCompany = ClientCompany,
            ProjectLeader = ProjectLeader
        };

        db.Projects.Add(project);
        db.Projects.Users.Add(ProjectLeader);
        return View();
    }

}
```

I am not sure how to add to the junction table to properly link users to projects. Please let me know if there is something wrong with my setup of the many-to-many relationship or if there is a way to fix the error message. Thank you!!

Comment: You can define the navigation properties for both one-many relationships as well as the skip navigation properties. There's a complete example in the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#join-entity-type-configuration

Comment: As the error message  said " DbSet does not contain a definition for Users". Try to add" public DbSet<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }" in IssueTrackerIdentityDbContext .

Comment: But shouldn't I not add the DbSet as the Users table is built in as the AspNetUsers table? I don't want to create a separate table called Users, instead I want to continue using the AspNetUsers table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the code like below:

```
 var project = new ProjectModel
        {
            Name = Name,
            Description = Description,
            Status = Status,
            ClientCompany = ClientCompany,
            ProjectLeader = ProjectLeader
        };

    //db.Projects.Add(project);
   // db.Projects.Users.Add(ProjectLeader);
      var User = new ApplicationUser()
        {
            FirstName="a"
        };
        project.Users.Add(User);
        db.Projects.Add(project);
```

Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70912657/asp-net-core-mvc-entity-framework-add-data-into-many-to-many-relationship/71031654#71031654) to know more.

Comment: @RyanTobin Could you describe your problem in a new post? Then include your query statement so that we can solve your problem.

Comment: I was able to solve, thank you!